# How to render a view normally after using render_to_string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails application I have an action which creates a XML document using an XML Builder template (`rxml`) template and `render_to_string`. The XML document is forwarded to a backend server.

After creating the XML document I want to send a normal HTML response to the browser, but somehow Rails is remembering the first call to `render_to_string`.

For example:

- Rails cannot find the default view `show.html.erb` because it looks for a `show.rxml`.
- Simply putting a `render 'mycontroller/show.html.erb'` at the bottom of my action handler makes Rails find the template, but the browser doesn't work because the response header's content type is `text/xml`.

Is there any way to use `render_to_string` without "tainting" the actual browser response?

**EDIT:** It seems that in Rails 2 `erase_render_results` would do the trick, but in Rails 3 it is no longer available.

Comment: Actually `erase_render_results` just sets a flag to false and erases the response_body - in the source for render_to_string the content type is explicitly set to nil. This seems more likely what the problem you've encountered is due to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pragmatic answer is that using a view file and two calls to render is Not The Rails Way: views are generally something that is sent to the client, and ActionPack is engineered to work that way.

That said, there's an easy way to achieve what you're trying to do. Rather than using ActionView, you could use Builder::XmlMarkup directly to generate your XML as a string:

```
def action_in_controller
  buffer = ""
  xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(buffer)

  # build your XML - essentially copy your view.xml.builder file here 
  xml.element("value")
  xml.element("value")

  # send the contents of buffer to your 3rd server

  # allow your controller to render your view normally
end
```

Have a look at [the Builder documentation](http://builder.rubyforge.org/) to see how it works.

The other feature of Builder that you can take advantage of is the fact that XML content is appended to the buffer using `<<`, so any IO stream can be used. Depending how you're sending content to the other server, you could wrap it all up quite nicely.

Of course, this could end up very messy and long, which is why you'd want to encapsulate this bit of functionality in another class, or as a method in your model.

Comment: The problem is that the XML data must also be available as a normal view, so following your advice means duplicating the code (in my case)  Nevertheless, this is what I did, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Seems as if this may be a bug in rails 3 (at least compared to the behavior of 2.3.x render_to_string).  In the [source for 2.3.8](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string) they clearly take extra steps to reset content_type and set the response body to nil (among other things).

```
def render_to_string
  ...
ensure
  response.content_type = nil
  erase_render_results
  reset_variables_added_to_assigns
end
```

but in the 3.0.3 source for [AbstractController::Rendering](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.3/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb)

```
def render_to_string(*args, &block)
  options = _normalize_args(*args, &block)
  _normalize_options(options)
  render_to_body(options)
end
```

You can see there is no explicit resetting of variables, render_to_body just returns view_context.render.   It is possible that content-type, response_body, etc are handled elsewhere and this is a red herring, but my first instinct would be to set

`response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'`

after your `render_to_string` before actually rendering.

Answer (score 2):

In migrating the actionwebservice gem I encountered the same error. In their code they circumvent the double render exception by calling the function `erase_render_results`.

This function is no longer available in rails3. Luckily the fix is quite easy (but it took me a while to find).

Inside actionwebservice the following function was called inside a controller to allow a second render:

```
def reset_invocation_response
  erase_render_results
  response.instance_variable_set :@header, Rack::Utils::HeaderHash.new(::ActionController::Response::DEFAULT_HEADERS.merge("cookie" => []))
end
```

To make this work in rails3, you just have to write:

```
def reset_invocation_response
  self.instance_variable_set(:@_response_body, nil)
  response.instance_variable_set :@header, Rack::Utils::HeaderHash.new("cookie" => [], 'Content-Type' => 'text/html')
end
```

Hope this helps.